# Search in System Preferences pane stopped working

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, system-settings

Since recently, searching in the System Preferences does not work any more on my Macbook Pro M1. When I enter any search string, just nothing happens, as if I hadn't typed in anything. Other users (logins) on the same Macbook experience the same issue.

Things I've tried to fix the issue

- started system in safe mode
- deleted ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist
- re-created Spotlight index (by excluding, then re-including MacintoshHD)

but to no avail.

What else could I try to fix the issue?

I'm on macOS Ventura. The issue may have occurred after the update to macOS 13.6.4, but not sure. I also have a Mac mini M1 that is on macOS 13.6.4, and it doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that this is the same issue as with the search in Mail App: a long-standing problem with the `corespotlightd` process.

Solution was

1. open Activity Monitor
2. search for 'corespotlightd'
3. force kill it

The process automatically restarts, then starts re-creating its search index. After that, search in System Preferences worked again.